# MD5 encode and decode

Tags: c#, md5

I have a function md5_encode

```
public string MD5_encode(string str_encode)
    {
        MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create();
        // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str_encode));

        // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
        // and create a string.
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
        // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        // Return the hexadecimal string.
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

i can't decode it. I search in internet and found something like that

```
public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, bool useHashing)
    {
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

        System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = new AppSettingsReader();
        // Get the key from config file
        string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("SecurityKey", typeof(String));
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(key);
        if (useHashing)
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            hashmd5.Clear();
        }
        else
            keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
    }
```

but i don't know that code work, Someone help me, decode function MD5_encode(string str_encode) or show me detail about different MD5_encode(string str_encode) and  Encrypt(string toEncrypt, bool useHashing)
tks a lot for any help :)

Comment: You cannot "decode" a MD5 hash, since it is a hash, not an encoded representation of the original data.

Comment: 1) MD5 is one-way. There is no efficient decode operation. 2) The code sample you found is one of the ugliest examples examples of encryption on the net. No idea why people keep copying it.

Comment: "Infeasible" to decode: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function and  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Intractability

Comment: You can show me, how i can encode by md5 a string

Comment: @user3050564 - you need to change your question (or ask another one) to tell what you want to do instead of asking for "encode by MD5". The fact that you named function `Something_encode` does not make this function actually do reversible encoding/encryption.

Answer (score 4):

`MD5_encode` uses MD5 (a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)) to generate a hash. The name is misleading as it isn't an encoding. A hash generate a value of a fixed size independent of the input, and cryptographic hash are especially designed not to be reversible.

`Encrypt` uses [Triple DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) to encrypt the input using as key either a value stored in the settings or the hash of this value.
You can decrypt the result of `Encrypt` using [`tdes.CreateDecryptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79w421xb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after removing the Base64 encoding.

*PS*: 3DES is old, you should use something more recent like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)
*PS*: ECB is insecure in a lot of cases, you should at least use CBC with a random IV.

Comment: How can you say decryption is not possible? How [they](http://www.md5online.org/) are doing this?

Comment: Are you serious ? They explain it on the main page **This algorithm is not reversible [...] Our tool uses a huge database**

Comment: The [link](http://www.md5online.org/) I provided decrypts the MD5 Encrypted data, so it alarms that MD5 is not secure. The                    option of AES looks smart. But it is returning some chines text. Can you please recomend any solution for that?

Comment: MD5 *IS NOT AN ENCRYPTION METHOD* they just have a database of a lot of (hash, cleartext) tuples and allow search in that. To encrypt use AES for symetric encryption yes. I doesn't return "chines text" it return a memory stream containing binary data, if you want a text representation use Base64 encoding or any other ASCII armoring method out there.

Answer (score 0):

Although MD5 is susceptible to a number of attacks that prove otherwise, MD5 is a hashing method. Hashes are designed to be one-way only. Just imagine if all of the hashing algorithms in the world today allowed anyone to easily get the original data from the hash data! Eeeeek!